# How to get value when model value lower than ng-min?

Tags: angularjs

> $scope.total < ng-min, $scope.total is undefined.

But i need to get that value to shown as change.

for example : if change -50, then cashier can easy to talk to customer if he need 50 more.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pay = null;
    $scope.total = 1000;
    $scope.change = 0;

    $scope.check = function() {
      $scope.change = $scope.pay - $scope.total;
      console.log('pay = ' + $scope.pay + ' , total = ' + $scope.total + ' , change = ' + $scope.change);
    };
  });

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   Total = {{ total }}
   <input type="number" ng-model="pay" ng-min="total" ng-change="check()">
   Change = {{ change }}
</body>
```

here my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4C9AuBI4q97VXXvXM59B?p=preview

Comment: This the default behavior of ng-min. You could add a if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use ng-min at all, because of this directive will pass only correct values, just add a condition to change-function. E.g

```
if($scope.change < 0){
   //do something
}
```

Also, better to change `$scope.pay = null;`  to `$scope.pay = 0;` if You want to avoid the type-errors

Comment: if $scope.pay = 0, i need to delete that 0 when i want to fill that form?